# How to do split each quantity and grouping by child customer order in one table

Tags: mysql

I have some data like in picture below on and need to perform some query.

[image: The Datas]

And then I try to produce result like the picture below, but I have trouble and don't know how to split qty by child customer order.

How to get results like picture 2?

This is the query I have tried in order to obtain the result I want:

```
SELECT item
    ,no_po
    ,sum(qty) as total
    ,parent_customer
    ,child_customer
    ,qty 
FROM `detail_order` 
WHERE received_date='2018-06-27' 
group by item 
ORDER BY item asc
```

[image: The Result What I wanted]

Comment: Can you create a demo table and data on sqlfiddle.com???

Comment: hello Mr Ravinder. yes, [this the sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f108f/2). thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select item, no_po, sum(qty) qty_total,
    sum(case when parent_customer='Customer B' and child_customer='ha' then qty else 0 end) as customer_b_ha,
    sum(case when parent_customer='Customer B' and child_customer='he' then qty else 0 end as customer_b_he,
    sum(case when parent_customer='Customer B' and child_customer='hi' then qty else 0 end as customer_b_hi,
    sum(case when parent_customer='Customer B' and child_customer='ho' then qty else 0 end as customer_b_ho,
    sum(case when parent_customer='Customer B' and child_customer='hu' then qty else 0 end as customer_b_hu,
    sum(case when parent_customer='Customer C' and child_customer='ha' then qty else 0 end as customer_c_ha,
    sum(case when parent_customer='Customer C' and child_customer='he' then qty else 0 end as customer_c_he,
    sum(case when parent_customer='Customer C' and child_customer='hi' then qty else 0 end as customer_c_hi,
    sum(case when parent_customer='Customer C' and child_customer='ho' then qty else 0 end as customer_c_ho,
    sum(case when parent_customer='Customer C' and child_customer='hu' then qty else 0 end as customer_c_hu
from detail_order
where received_date='2018-06-27' 
group by item, no_po
order by item asc, no_po
```

Comment: hai mrs Indiri, thank you for you response.

that query it's working nicely with some little editing. But, can I do the looping based on the child's name of the consumer ?? when i try to change "sum (case when parent_customer IN ('Customer B', 'Customer C') and child_customer IN ('ha', 'hi', 'hu', 'he', 'ho') then qty else 0 end) as tags "(using only one line). The result only gives one column. Thank you very much

Comment: Each case statement is it's own column. "sum (case when parent_customer IN ('Customer B', 'Customer C') and child_customer IN ('ha', 'hi', 'hu', 'he', 'ho') then qty else 0 end) as tags " is the same as sum(qty) because you are including all permutations in a single column. If you only want to break it up by the child and don't care which parent then you could reduce it to 5 columns by removing the parent_customer='B' or combine just *that* part to "sum (case when parent_customer IN ('Customer B', 'Customer C') and child_customer ='ha' then qty else 0 end) as tags_ha ".